# Slider works on certain browsers, but not on others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have this slider on www.Guguta.com that if you open it with IE or Firefox, it works well.
If you open with Chrome or Safari ..the main pictured does NOT show.

Also the Mouse Click on the small images, should load that small picture into the main one, but again on Chrome and Safari does NOT work.

The JS Script that manages the slider is initiated at "scripts.cs"
Full source code can be downloaded from here: 
**www.guguta.com/slider.zip**

Any help/tip will be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced,
Developer

Comment: or firefox on mac also chrome on mac doesn't work

Comment: it could also help if you paste your code above

Comment: also what script does what??? there are like 7 of them is it the script.js??

Comment: guys he put a link in his question so you can download it, stop being lazy and download it and look at it

Comment: exploring the elements with chrome, `canvas` width and height are `0` and the tag is not closed ... isn't a bug in the cycle plugin? who is the author? where is the repository?

Comment: @JFK the canvas gets added by the jquery rotate plugin which has a bug but hes using a old version of it which is updated which i said in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. this line was stuffing it up

```
$('.slider-item a').find('img').each(function () {
        $(this).rotateRight(-2);    
    });
```

and I replaced it with

```
$('.slider-item a').find('img').each(function () {
        degree = -2;
        $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                        'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',

        }); 
    });
```

note:: this will only work in modern browsers like, webkit based browsers, ie 9 and firefox (i think 3.5 and higher).

Edit:

Also I noted you have a older jquery rotate plugin if you update it 
download link http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/downloads/detail?name=jQueryRotate.2.2.js

and then do this

```
 $('.slider-item a').find('img').each(function () {
            $(this).rotate(-2); 
        });
```

also i recon 1.5 deg is better than 2deg (and yes you can do 1.5 i tried it looks a lot better)

it will fix this hope this helps

Ryan

Comment: Oh Niceeee ...I would have never imagined. Well, thanks a lot. So that you know this is for a site to will help homeless finding back their Dignity by providing them a Roof. It's called RightToDignity.com and should go live soon very soon. Thanks again, seriously !!

Comment: @Developer Your welcome, love helping and sounds like a really good idea, would like to see it :-D